# Django: How to submit the current user's username through a form without the user having to enter it

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm looking for a simple way to have a django form submit the currently logged-in user's username behind the scenes when the user submits a form. I'd like this to happen automatically.

I've seen examples in other stackoverflow entries where the **init** function is called. However, I find this way to be very messy and verbose.

I'm using Django 2.2.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. You'd better add detailed code snippet to get attention. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good, standard way to do this.

The best way is to use the generic class-based view called CreateView. Here is a clear explanation in the Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user

I'll use the example from the docs in this explanation.

**First:** Use a basic model for the form. Nothing special here. (models.py)

```python
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # ...
```

**Second:** Create a class-based view. In that class-based view, modify "def form_valid(self, form)" as shown in the docs example below. (views.py)

```python
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**Third:** Define urls. Add the regular "as_view()" as per all class-based views. (urls.py)

```python
app_name = 'logs'

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.AuthorCreate.as_view(), name = "author_create"),
]
```

**Fourth:** The CreateView generic class-based view has a default template name linked to it (see [django docs for CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#createview), under the "template_name" attribute). The default template name follows the convention of "authorcreate_form.html". So create a html template with filename following that convention in the app's templates folder. The following template worked for me. (.html)

```python
<form method="POST" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Again, this is the basic example that's provided in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) to pass a user's username through a user form. This worked well for me.